# Find compressed files and output line

Tags: bash, compression

I want to output a specific line of several compressed files. Due to my research I think I have to extract the file and afterwards grep my strings. E.g. `gunzip -c` just outputs to `STDOUT` where I can further process.

I tried:

```
find path/to/files -name archive.gz | xargs gunzip -c | awk 'NR==100{print}'
```

which just outputs one string (the one from the second file). Without the `xargs` I am getting the error: **gzip: stdin: not in gzip format**

If there actually is an option for grep, sed, awk, perl, or any other standard bash tool, I would be pleased to get informed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `-exec` option in order to issue a shell command:

```
find path/to/files -name archive.gz -exec sh -c "gzip -dc {} | awk 'NR==100'" \;
```

This would execute the command for every output generated by the `find` command.